# Pandas Dataframe to dict grouping by column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Subject_id    Subject    Score    
Subject_1        Math        5                 
Subject_1    Language        4                 
Subject_1       Music        8
Subject_2        Math        8                 
Subject_2    Language        3                 
Subject_2       Music        9
```

And I want to convert it into a dictionary, grouping by subject_id

```
{'Subject_1': {'Math': 5,
               'Language': 4,
               'Music': 8},
{'Subject_2': {'Math': 8,
               'Language': 3,
               'Music': 9}
}
```

If I would have only  one Subject, then I could so:

```
my_dict['Subject_1'] = dict(zip(df['Subject'],df['Score']))
```

But since I have several subjects the list of keys repeats, so I cannot use directly a zip.

Dataframes has a `.to_dict('index')` method but I need to be able to group by a certain column when creating the dictionary.

How could I achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with custom lambda function and last convert output `Series` [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = (df.groupby('Subject_id')
       .apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['Subject'],x['Score'])))
       .to_dict())

print (d)
{'Subject_2': {'Math': 8, 'Music': 9, 'Language': 3}, 
 'Subject_1': {'Math': 5, 'Music': 8, 'Language': 4}}
```

Detail:

```
print (df.groupby('Subject_id').apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['Subject'],x['Score']))))

Subject_id
Subject_1    {'Math': 5, 'Music': 8, 'Language': 4}
Subject_2    {'Math': 8, 'Music': 9, 'Language': 3}
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `to_dict` with `pivot`

```
In [29]: df.pivot('Subject_id', 'Subject', 'Score').to_dict('index')
Out[29]:
{'Subject_1': {'Language': 4L, 'Math': 5L, 'Music': 8L},
 'Subject_2': {'Language': 3L, 'Math': 8L, 'Music': 9L}}
```

Or,

```
In [25]: df.set_index(['Subject_id', 'Subject']).unstack()['Score'].to_dict('index')
Out[25]:
{'Subject_1': {'Language': 4L, 'Math': 5L, 'Music': 8L},
 'Subject_2': {'Language': 3L, 'Math': 8L, 'Music': 9L}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Zero that you can use asterisk (*) for more comfort and or additional filtering via list comprehension of df.columns

```
import io 
import pandas as pd

TESTDATA = """
Subject_id;    Subject;    Score    
Subject_1;        Math;        5                 
Subject_1;    Language;        4                 
Subject_1;       Music;        8
Subject_2;        Math;        8                 
Subject_2;    Language;        3                 
Subject_2;       Music;        9

"""
df = pd.read_csv(  io.StringIO(TESTDATA)  , sep=";").applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)

df.pivot(*df.columns).to_dict('index')
```

---

```
{'Subject_1': {'Language': 4, 'Math': 5, 'Music': 8},
'Subject_2': {'Language': 3, 'Math': 8, 'Music': 9}}
```